# VS 2010 function's parameter information keeps disappearing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, parameters

My VS2010 keeps turning off the parameter information, I mean that tooltip that tells you the signature of a function. If I turn it on at Text Editor --> C# --> General --> Paramter information within half an hour I have it turned off.
Before I drown in VS2010 documentation maybe someone tells me the reason for such a peculiar behaviour? 
Anyone?

Comment: VS2010 doesn't turn that option off.  Add-ins do.

Comment: I would have thought so, but unfortunately for me, it is not. I invested my time, uninstalled all the add-ins and still have intellisense broken.